# Assuming two notebooks have American keyboards, one of them is a GNOME and the other macOS, how to handle input in Brazilian Portuguese symmetrically?

Tags: macos, keyboard, unix, input-source

I have two computers:

(i) My **old** one: DELL XPS 13, **American Keyboard**, running NixOS (Linux distribution) and GNOME Desktop Environment

(ii) My **new** one: A MacBook Air M1, **American Keyboard**, running Monterey 12.5 and Apple's default Desktop Environemnt.

It is important to highlight that, despite the American keyboards, I am Brazilian and I need Brazilian Portuguese input to type things such as "ç", "ã", "é", "à".

Right. Things used to work in my old Linux. There are just 3 options for input in Portuguese in GNOME. And only one for Brazilian Portuguese:

[image]

My config was:

[image]

To type things such as `ã` I need to press the following keys, first the orange one, then the blue one:

[image]

Now, I would like to have exactly the same keybindings to provide the same character in a macOS. How to do it considering there are 4 options for Portuguese input (3 for Brazilian Portuguese) in my macOS machine?

[image]

Comment: @TomGewecke, maybe I missed something here. Thanks for trying to help. But, I believe I am correct here: https://youtube.com/shorts/4qH016NM9uI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the **same** keybindings for the **same** characters in the two **different** machines using **different** Operational Systems, choose *Brazilian - ABNT2* on the Mac machine.

[image]

Comment: There are also ways to change keybindings on MacOS and probably on NixOS.  The US keyboard on MacOS also has "press and hold" to support all characters in Portuguese and others.  Maybe something like that can be installed in nixOS.

Comment: @TomGewecke, thanks for trying to help. Be careful with editions, you changed it to the wrong symbol. Now, I have re-edited it to be `ã`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, @TomGewecke. Maybe I missed something, but I believe I am correct: https://youtube.com/shorts/4qH016NM9uI

Comment: You have fixed it now, all is correct when you use the  "Brazilian ABNT2" input source instead of "Brazilian"   I removed earlier comments.